# Plotting pi digits as connection bundles with ggraph

Tags: r, ggraph, tidygraph

I'm looking to plot the digits of Pi as heirarchical edge bundles, as shown in this image

[image]

Here, the digits of Pi are grouped by their colour, and then each digit has an edge drawn to the digit that follows it (i.e., if Pi is 3.141, then 3 would have an edge drawn to 1, 1 would have an edge to 4, and so on through the digits).

This is the code I have so far

```
library(ggraph)
library(tidygraph)

dat_lagged <- structure(list(line = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), digit = c("3", 
"1", "4", "1", "5", "9"), digit_lagged = c("1", "4", "1", "5", 
"9", "2"), group = c("3", "1", "4", "1", "5", "9")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

from <- as.numeric(dat_lagged$digit)
to <- as.numeric(dat_lagged$digit_lagged)

ggraph(dat_lagged, 'dendrogram', circular = TRUE) +
  geom_conn_bundle(aes(colour = stat(group)),
                   data = get_con(from, to),
                   edge_alpha = 0.25)
```

However this is throwing the error

```
Error in if (is.numeric(v) && any(v < 0)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was able to create something similar using a linear layout. First, create a tbl_graph object from a data.frame with from, to, and the rank of the "from" number.

I use `library(Rmpfr)` to obtain 1000 pi digits for this.

```
library(Rmpfr)
digits <- Const("pi",1000)
#convert to string
pistr <- substr(capture.output(digits)[2],5,nchar(capture.output(digits)[2]))
#reformat string type object to from,to list of lists
reform <- lapply(seq(2,nchar(pistr)),function(x) {c(as.numeric(substr(pistr,x-1,x-1)),as.numeric(substr(pistr,x,x)))})
#bind list of lists to dataframe
do.call(rbind,reform) %>% data.frame -> pi1000
#remove NAs introduced by string of decimal .
pi1000 <- pi1000 %>% slice(-1)
#rename columns 
colnames(pi1000) <- c('from','to')
#reintroduce first connection, 3 -> 1
pi1000$from[1] <- 3
#remove final from,to line with missing "to" number
pi1000 <- pi1000 %>% filter(!is.na(from))
#add a rank for each from, to - we will use this to numerically "jitter" the connections later
pi1000$rank <- seq(1,length(pi1000[,1]))

#next, arrange from,to connections by 'from', so that when tbl_graph is called, nodes are ordered numerically
pi1000 <- pi1000 %>% arrange(from)

#convert from,to DF to tbl_graph
#the tbl_graph's edges are converted so that the from,to now refer to the index of the nodes (i.e. x+1)
piggraph <- pi1000 %>% as_tbl_graph
```

Once the tbl_graph is formatted as such it becomes easier to create the plot with simpler ggraph grammar, but the plot appears to fall apart when set to `circular=T`. The 'linear' layout lets you control where edges land using a single variable - would love to see an answer that uses a circular format!

```
piggraph %>% ggraph(layout='linear') + 
    #arc2 creates a plot that can be colored by node by referring to the nodes of the tbl_graph (node.name)
    #add a component rank/length(rank) to make the edges jitter according to when the number happens in pi's sequence
    geom_edge_arc2(aes(x=x+(rank/(length(pi1000$rank))),color=as.factor(node.name))) +
    #add a label for each node and center it with nudge_x
    geom_node_text(aes(label=name),nudge_x = 0.5)
```

[The resulting graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qz4F.jpg)